# Content Porter 2009 SP1 Reports "Unable to get list of child items"

Tags: tridion

I can connect to the Content Manager and I'm using an administrative user, but when it starts to show me the contents of the Content Manager, I get a pop-up dialogue that says, "Unable to get list of child items".

I have 4 publications defined, the Default Items, a Root Structure Group and a Page in the Root, so I should have a hierarchy of items to choose from.

Nothing is reported in the Content Porter client logs and I've seen only this entry in the server Tridion Event log, but I think that's only because I continued the export with only the server selected -- and obviously without any child items, there was nothing to export.

> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\Content Porter\temp\export_9a1e48db0f124f19b5e519f179faf8c8.zip'.
>
> Component: Content Porter
>   Errorcode: 0
>   User: TRIDION\adminuser
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.downloadfile.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> Inner exception:

I'm running Tridion 2011 SP1 on Windows Server 2008 64-bit, if that has any relevance.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you recently install hotfix CP_3.1.0.75326?

Double check you followed steps 7 & 8 in the hotfix README:

7 - Copy Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.CommonFacade.dll from this hotfix to the "Tridion\Content Porter\bin" and "Tridion\Content Porter\ImportExportService\bin" folders (replace original files)
8 - Copy cp.application, cp.exe.manifest and Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.CommonFacade.dll.deploy files from this hotfix to the "Tridion\Content Porter\ImportExportService\Client" folder (replace original files)

Also ensure you uninstalled / reinstalled the CP client from the client system you are using (step 11 in the README).

Comment: Doh!  While I copied Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.CommonFacade.dll to the "Tridion\Content Porter\bin", I neglected to copy it over to "Tridion\Content Porter\ImportExportService\bin".  Thank you!